# What is the need of 'or default' in this python code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, binary-operators

Here is the code all_jokes is a dictionary that has some categories mapped to jokes.

```py
def select_joke(category):
    jokes = all_jokes[category or 'default']
    shuffle(jokes)
    return jokes[0]
```

Comment: Please don't forget to accept your answer to help future users looking for the same answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Returns the value of the `default` key in the `all_jokes` dict if the value of `category` wasn't [truthy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39983695/what-is-truthy-and-falsy-how-is-it-different-from-true-and-false):

```py
from random import shuffle

all_jokes = {
    'joke1': ['This is joke1'],
    'joke2': ['This is joke2'],
    'default': ['This is default joke']
}

def select_joke(category):
    jokes = all_jokes[category or 'default']
    shuffle(jokes)
    return jokes[0]

print("----------------------------------------")
print(f"input:{0} output:{select_joke(0)}")
print(f"input:{None} output:{select_joke(None)}")
print(f"input:{''} output:{select_joke('')}")
print("----------------------------------------")
```

**Output:**

```
----------------------------------------
input:0 output:This is default joke
input:None output:This is default joke
input: output:This is default joke
----------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

As in many other languages, `or` returns the first element if it's "truthy", the second one otherwise.

In this case, if `category` is 0, or None, or the empty string, etc., we get `all_jokes['default']`. Otherwise, we get `all_jokes[category]`.

Answer (score 0):

**It means,**

> *if `category` is false (or empty or None) use 'default' as key*.

Probably without knowing the rest of the code, `all_jokes` is a dictionary which contains a `default` option.

Answer (score 0):

Python's `and` and `or` operators are equivalent to the following if expressions:

```py
# NB: These work as intended for boolean values.
(a or b) is (a if a else b)
(a and b) is (b if a else a)
```

```
def select_joke(category):
    """Equivalent to your code."""
    jokes = all_jokes[category if category else 'default']
    shuffle(jokes)
    return jokes[0]
```

This allows call sites which are fine accepting `'default'` jokes to pass in `''` or `None`. Python code tends to look more beautiful when `or` is used in place of if expressions which match this pattern (replacing a falsy value with another), especially if you use function arguments which default to a falsy value.

---

As a side note, you can simplify your function with [`random.choice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice):

```py
def select_joke(category=None):
    return random.choice(all_jokes[category or 'default'])


select_joke()          # category will be 'default'.
select_joke('default') # category will be 'default'.
select_joke(None)      # category will be 'default'.
select_joke('')        # category will be 'default'.
select_joke('puns')    # category will be 'puns'.
```